# Use os.system to install a program on apt-get?

Tags: python, installation, sudo, apt-get

Is it possible to use `os.system` to install a program on apt-get. Here's what I've tried so far:

```
if comm == "install":
  os.system("gnome-terminal -e sudo apt-get install"+args)
```

(args being the argument supplied to the command)

Comment: Sure you can do it. But what results do you expect? And what problems do you face?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, but I'd personally avoid using os.system() (or preferred subprocess module calls) for python apt interface: [homepage](http://apt.alioth.debian.org/python-apt-doc/library/index.html)

It gives you much more flexibility than plain os.system() (e.g. installation progress reporting etc.)